# PGS4A build fail on /google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library

Tags: python, android

I've got problem with building my app for android with PGS4A. After doing android.py installsdk and android.py configure myapp I ended up with this error from android build myapp install release:

```
I'm using Ant to build the package.

Buildfile: /home/jedrek/pgs4a-0.9.6/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/jedrek/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Matinf-1
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:

BUILD FAILED
/home/jedrek/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:459: ../play_licensing resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /home/jedrek/pgs4a-0.9.6/android-sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library

Total time: 0 seconds

The build seems to have failed.
```

Comment: Let's be honest. The package is so outdated and poorly maintained.

Comment: I noticed this, but I haven't found nothing as simple and easy to learn as this. So I think it's still good package for simpler games (if only it works :) )